# Is April too late to prune my fig tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, figs

I have a purple and gold variety fig tree that's been established for about three or four seasons. I had been cutting it all the way back every winter, but this season, I missed my opportunity (for no good reason). Is it too late to cut it back now, in April? There's no new growth as of yet, but I'm seeing one or two tiny leaves starting to appear at the base. The branches from last season's growth are three to four feet high. I'm in Western Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. Pruning now would reduce the sensibly the strength of the plant, so it the plant is already weak don't prune it. On the other hand, if the plant is strong, you can do some pruning, but I would not do it as hard as I would do it in winter.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a shot. I cut away some of the shoots that were clearly diseased or dead and cut back by about a third some of the others on which I'm starting to see new growth further down. We'll see what happens.